# Design pattern for a single form Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns

My app is expanding, but the reqs dictate that there should be only one window open at all times, think of Nodepad where there is a menu, with each menu item different functionality but only one window open at all times as opposed to Excel where a user may have few windows open at once.

So in terms of Windows forms, I was thinking of placing a form within a main form. Then i could load an embedded form needed depending on the user menu choice. OR I could be adding controls to the main form (and their events dynamically depending on the user menu choice). I would use a presenter class for that.

That's just two solution I would use. Do you guys have any tips/experience on how to do it better?

I realize now that I would have to re-write parts of my app, but let's pretend i am starting from scratch.

Comment: As per JP's answer, it sounds like your trying to describe SDI/MDI  but the language of your question doesn't really make sense.  Please clarify if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't embed Forms, it's not what Forms are for. And it's not necessary.

Put the UI of your modules/sections on UserControls. That keeps it nice and modular and you keep your options open: those UserControls can be directly embedded (1 at a time) in the MainForm or in MDI ChildWindows or in TabPages or ...

Use a Base UserControl (Visual Inheritance) and/or a Interface to implement common functionality.

Comment: I think that's what I need. Do you happen to have any tutorials (simple ones that show how to do this practice)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are describing is [Multiple-Document Interface (MDI) Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983667(VS.71).aspx).  Fortunately, there is great support for MDI in WinForms.  Here's a quick [intro](http://www.dotnetjunkies.com/quickstart/winforms/doc/WinFormsMDI.aspx).

Comment: I'd like to upvote this but I'm not 100% sure if it's answering the question because the language of the question is unclear.

Comment: I only went by the tag, so if it's a C# winform, it should apply. :)

Comment: AdamRalph, sorry for not being clear. My application should resemble Nodepad rather than Excel. In Excel you can have several windows open, but in Notepad every time you click to open a doc, the previous one gets closed . Hope this is clear, if its not, I am not sure how else I could explain it. Hence, MDI doesn't make sense for me, as MDI is: "Multiple-document interface (MDI) applications allow you to display multiple documents at the same time, with each document displayed in its own window"

Answer (score 0):

If your requirements are "one window - multiple functionallity" I would certainly go for a composable UI style of development. The [Smart Client Software Factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480482.aspx) is a good starting point imo.